# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DefaultRoutingSearchParameters'

Tags: python, pulp, or-tools

I have installed the ortools exactly as mentioned in [this](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/installing/binary) link.

After that, I copied vehicle routing problem from the documentation and tried to execute.I am using python 2.7.12 in my system.

I ended up with the below error:

```
   >>python or_test.py 
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "or_test.py", line 120, in <module>
      main()
      File "or_test.py", line 52, in main
     search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 
  'DefaultRoutingSearchParameters'
```

Example problem link :
https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/vehicle_routing

Comment: I followed those given steps pip install --upgrade ortools.
Have I missed something??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [example from the repo](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/tsp.py), you can get default parameters like this instead:

```
 search_parameters = pywrapcp.RoutingModel.DefaultSearchParameters()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked...Do you have any idea why the previous declaration was not working